# How to access the underlying Lucene index in ElasticSearch custom handler?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

My current project involves search over highly customised Solr indices. It turns out that the best way to query those is to use the Lucene API.
In Solr, I can access the underlying Lucene index using:

```
public void process(ResponseBuilder responseBuilder) throws IOException {
    SolrIndexSearcher sir = responseBuilder.req.getSearcher();
    BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
    Query tq = new TermQuery(new Term("content", "test"));
    bq.add(tq, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    TopDocs td = sir.search(bq, 20);
    }
```

Now, ElasticSearch seems to hide the Lucene functionalities. Is there a way to expose the Lucene index at ES query handler level, or to query it similarly to the example above (i.e. direct querying over index fields) using the ES API?